# Eclipse doesnt generate MainActivity,Layout xml and the launcer icon which is under drawable-ldpi folder

Tags: java, android

I create a new android app and eclipse doesnt generate MainActivity and layout xml and also the project includes appcombat_7 and appcombat_4 together is that the cause of my issue if so how can i fix that
As you see;

[image: I got these bugs]

[image: As you see;]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the android application, use "empty activity" instead of "blank" activity. Worked for me and other people

Answer (score 0):

Whenever creating your project select create activity check box in create activity screen.

Example: select ->New android application project,one window will be open in that eneter your project name.

select -> Next

select->Next
select->check create activity